# gamekit UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Must 'gamekit' entry in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities be present to game center to work?  I've been posting scores to leaderboard, from three different accounts, on three different devices, but the scores never shows up.  and all of them says "Not Ranked"

It is frustrating.  My currently submitted App (still waiting for the review) does not have 'gamekit' entry in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in plist.

Is that why?  or that does not matter?

Any help appreciated in advance!

frustrated in new york.

Answer (score 0):

My app isn't submitted yet but it successfully submits scores in sandbox mode. Also achievements. And it does not include anything about gamekit or game center in the required device capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

oh well, what do you know.  It started working right after I posted this question.  hah!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not mandatory to have the **gamekit** entry in **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** key.

Your Game Center SNS features will still work in both development and AppStore Distribution regardless of that the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key specifies.

I've succesfully submitted a new app that supports GameCenter and that was lacking the "gamekit" value from info.plist and the AppStore retail version worked just fine.

Comment: ps: added this answer since I also needed to know if it's mandatory to have the gamekit entry and this is the only place where i could find a relevant answer so i also wanted to double confirm.